# Laravel 5 | Image Upload | Cant get datas of uploaded variable

Tags: php, laravel, image-uploading, laravel-5

I use ,

```
$up = request::file('image')->move('../public/images');
```

to Upload image to "Public/images" directory.

i try to know datas of "$up", by using "dd()".

I get datas as,

```
 UploadedFile {#183 ▼
 -test: false
 -originalName: "Brackpoints.png"
 -mimeType: "image/png"
 -size: 148276
 -error: 0
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "phpmU8PvU"
  basename: "phpmU8PvU"
  pathname: "/tmp/phpmU8PvU"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/phpmU8PvU"
  aTime: 2016-02-15 13:57:39
  mTime: 2016-02-15 13:57:39
  cTime: 2016-02-15 13:57:39
  inode: 1443211
  size: 148276
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 900
  group: 900
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

If i try "print_r()", then i get,

```
 Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object
 (
  [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
[originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => Brackpoints.png
[mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/png
[size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 148276
[error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
[pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/phpMhUyh0
[fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpMhUyh0
 )

   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File Object
  (
      [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => ../public/images/phpMhUyh0
      [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpMhUyh0
  )
```

Here, I want to get the Name and type of the Image...

How could i get ?

Answer (score 5):

```
$up->getClientOriginalName();

$up->getMimeType();
```

Comment: I get error, when i use $up->getClientOriginalName();
.........................

      Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component    \HttpFoundation\File\File::getClientOriginalName()                                             


...........................
But $up->getMimeType(); return its Mime type.

Comment: Why Your object changed? It was `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` and now its `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File` There is no way to get original name from this second type.

Comment: `File\File` i file already moved, so You have to get original name before that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo $up->originalName;
```